# Letter frequency in python

Tags: python

I need to make a program that prints out the frequency of letters in a text
file and compares that frequency with that of another in python.

So far I am able to print the number of times a letter occurs, but the
percentage frequency I get is wrong. I think it is because I need my program to count only
the number of letters in the file by removing all the spaces and other
characters.

```
def addLetter (x):
    result = ord(x) - ord(a)
    return result


#start of the main program
#prompt user for a file

while True:
    speech = raw_input("Enter file name:")

    wholeFile = open(speech, 'r+').read()
    lowlet = wholeFile.lower()
    letters= list(lowlet)
    alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    n = len(letters)
    f = float(n)
    occurrences = {}
    d = {}


    #number of letters
    for x in alpha:
        occurrences[x] = letters.count(x)
        d[x] =(occurrences[x])/f
    for x in occurrences:
        print x, occurrences[x], d[x]
```

This is the output

```
Enter file name:dems.txt
a 993 0.0687863674148
c 350 0.0242449431976
b 174 0.0120532003325
e 1406 0.0973954003879
d 430 0.0297866444999
g 219 0.015170407315
f 212 0.0146855084511
i 754 0.0522305347742
h 594 0.0411471321696
k 81 0.00561097256858
j 12 0.000831255195345
m 273 0.0189110556941
l 442 0.0306178996952
o 885 0.0613050706567
n 810 0.0561097256858
q 9 0.000623441396509
p 215 0.0148933222499
s 672 0.0465502909393
r 637 0.0441257966196
u 305 0.021127736215
t 1175 0.0813937378775
w 334 0.0231366029371
v 104 0.00720421169299
y 212 0.0146855084511
x 13 0.000900526461624
z 6 0.000415627597672
Enter file name:
```

The program does print in columns, but I'm not really sure how to display that here.

the frequency for "a" should be .0878

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Your "f" variable contains the total length of the list, not the number of alphabetic characters in the list. Also - don't cheat on your homework using SO. If you don't learn it yourself you won't ever learn it.

Comment: Yes this is a hw assignment.  I wasn't trying to cheat.  I just hit a dead end and needed some direction.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [translator recipe](http://books.google.com/books?id=1Shx_VXS6ioC&pg=PT54&dq=Python+Cookbook+translator+Perkins+Hettinger&hl=en&ei=sThsTafwEoSs8AbDxPzaCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) to drop all characters not in `alpha`.
Since doing so makes `letters` contain nothing but characters from `alpha`, `n` is now the correct denominator.

You could then use a `collections.defaultdict(int)` to count the occurrences of the letters:

```
import collections
import string

def translator(frm='', to='', delete='', keep=None):
    # Python Cookbook Recipe 1.9
    # Chris Perkins, Raymond Hettinger
    if len(to) == 1: to = to * len(frm)
    trans = string.maketrans(frm, to)
    if keep is not None:
        allchars = string.maketrans('', '')
        # delete is expanded to delete everything except
        # what is mentioned in set(keep)-set(delete)
        delete = allchars.translate(allchars, keep.translate(allchars, delete))
    def translate(s):
        return s.translate(trans, delete)
    return translate

alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
keep_alpha=translator(keep=alpha)

while True:
    speech = raw_input("Enter file name:")
    wholeFile = open(speech, 'r+').read()
    lowlet = wholeFile.lower()
    letters = keep_alpha(lowlet)
    n = len(letters)
    occurrences = collections.defaultdict(int)    
    for x in letters:
        occurrences[x]+=1
    for x in occurrences:
        print x, occurrences[x], occurrences[x]/float(n)
```

Comment: If you are running on Python 2.7/3.1, there is also the `collections.Counter` class, [primarily designed to work with positive integers to represent running counts](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch for the help.  I had no idea how to do this.  I can continue the project now.

Answer (score 3):

```
import collections
import re
from __future__ import division

file1 = re.subn(r"\W", "", open("file1.txt", "r").read())[0].lower()
counter1 = collections.Counter(file1)
for k, v in counter1.iteritems():
   counter1[k] = v / len(file1)

file2 = re.subn(r"\W", "", open("file2.txt", "r").read())[0].lower()
counter2 = collections.Counter(file2)
for k, v in counter2.iteritems():
   counter2[k] = v / len(file2)
```

Note: requires Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a really straight forward way to do it:

```
while True:
    speech = raw_input("Enter file name:")

    wholeFile = open(speech, 'r+').read()
    lowlet = wholeFile.lower()

    alphas = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    # lets set default values first
    occurrences = {letter : 0 for letter in alphas }
    # occurrences = dict(zip(alphas, [0]*len(alphas))) # for python<=2.6

    # total number of valid letters
    total = 0

    # iter everything in the text
    for letter in lowlet:
        # if it is a valid letter then it is in occurrences
        if letter in occurrences:
            # update counts
            total += 1
            occurrences[letter] += 1

    # now print the results:
    for letter, count in occurrences.iteritems():
        print letter, (1.0*count/total)
```

As you notices you need the total number of valid letters in the text before you can calculate the frequency. Either you filter the text before processing it, or you combine the filtering with the processing, which is what I do here.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was not sure how to filter out the things that I don't need. Your method uses a dictionary which we aren't allowed to use.  I was able to use unutbu's method.

Comment: @SimplyZ: Are you sure? You used two dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.  I hadn't noticed that earlier.

Comment: @SimplyZ: You are probably supposed to use a list then, where `freq[0]` stands for `a`, `freq[1]` is for `b` and so on ...