# Letter Frequency: get frequencies to print in order from most to least used

Tags: python

I want to write a program that reads letters from a text file, ignoring symbols and whitespace, and prints the counts of each letter in order from most common to least common.

IN ADDITION, I am working on this for my first programming class, so I am not allowed to use counters.

I have this so far:

```
name= raw_input("Enter file name:")
fl= open(name, 'r+').read()
lw= fl.lower()
ws= lw.replace(' ','')
sm= ws.translate(None, ",-!.;?:")
occ= {}
alpha= list ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
for x in alpha:
    occ[x]= sm.count(x)
for x in occ:
    print x, occ[x]
```

Pretend the text file is something like: "I am highly confused by this?"

Then the program will go through it's programming and do this: "iamhighlyconfusedbythis"

But right now it only show something like this:

```
1   a
1   b
1   c
1   d
1   e
1   f
1   g
3   h
3   i
0   j
0   k
1   l
1   m
1   n
1   o
0   p
0   q
0   r
2   s
1   t
1   u
0   v
0   w
0   x
2   y
0   z
```

But I want the result to look like:

```
3   h
3   i
2   s
2   y
1   e
1   f
1   g
1   a
1   b
1   l
1   m
1   n
1   o
1   c
1   t
1   u
1   d
0   j
0   k
0   p
0   q
0   r
0   v
0   w
0   x
0   z
```

I used ideas from:

spyshyguy

[Determining Letter Frequency Of Cipher Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992408/determining-letter-frequency-of-cipher-text-in-python)

SimplyZ

[Letter frequency in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148903/letter-frequency-in-python)

Comment: Samuel, please clean this up. It's very hard to read as is.

Comment: Sorry Michael Petrotta and jamylak I accidently took the wrong program and I just edited it to put the right one in... THIS is the one that I got so far... Sorry again...

Comment: @JoelCornett- In a way yes in a way no... It is no graded practice in a book that I just really want to understand...

Comment: You don't actually have to make a list of alpha: `list('abc...xyz')`  If you just use the string in a `for` loop, Python will automatically loop over the string, one character at a time.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution to updated problem**

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import string
>>> text = 'I am highly confused by this?'.lower().translate(None,string.punctuation+' ')
>>> c = defaultdict(int)
>>> c.update({letter:0 for letter in string.lowercase[:26]}) #Initialize each letter of alphabet to 0
>>> for letter in text:
        c[letter] += 1


>>> for letter,freq in sorted(c.iteritems(),key=lambda (l,f): (-f,l)): #Sort by frequency in descending order by making frequency negative then by letter in ascending order
        print freq, letter


3 h
3 i
2 s
2 y
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
1 e
1 f
1 g
1 l
1 m
1 n
1 o
1 t
1 u
0 j
0 k
0 p
0 q
0 r
0 v
0 w
0 x
0 z
```

**Solution to original problem:** 
You could use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import string
>>> text = 'I am highly confused by this?'.translate(None,string.punctuation+' ')
>>> print ' '.join('%d %s'%(freq,letter) for letter,freq in Counter(x).most_common())
3 h 2 i 2 s 2 y 1 a 1 c 1 b 1 e 1 d 1 g 1 f 1 I 1 m 1 l 1 o 1 n 1 u 1 t
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and answer, but I am not allowed to use Counter, so is there another way?

Comment: Did you mention that in the question? I didn't see that when reading it, anyway i will make a new solution to the question now that it has been changed.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `defaultdict`?

Comment: Once again I am making foolish and newbie moves... I edit it once again to include everything that I know. Thank you for putting up with jamlak and everyone else that read this!!! :)

Comment: @ jamylak - I do not even know what defaultdict are yet?

Comment: You said you aren't allowed to use `counter`, i'm not sure why so i'll assume you can use `defaultdict`

Comment: @jamylak- Is defauldict just dictionaries (allowed) or something a little bit more? (Sorry about this, but I am just keep on getting even more confuse as the time goes one... I been working on this since last week)

Comment: `defaultdict` is just like a dictionary although when you try to access a key that doesn't exist it sets the value of the key to a default value and returns it depending on which data type you are using. eg. a `defaultdict(int)` returns 0 if you try to access a key that doesn't exist. You can google `defaultdict` for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this,

```
from operator import itemgetter
for k,v in sorted(occ.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print k, v
```

But there are better ways to count the letters, such as `collections.Counter`

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response, but the python program that I am using is Python 2.7 and it does not know what Counter are.... In addition, when I took your programming and try to incorporate with mine it resulted in an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\hell\LtoFreq.py", line 11, in <module>
    for k,v in sorted(occ.items, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
NameError: name 'occ' is not defined

Comment: should be `items()` ? Also, it actually won't end up sorting the secondary key (letters) in forward order

Comment: @SamuelM. - Counter was added in Python 2.7, so it should exist. You need to import it from [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) though.

Comment: @ Brendan Long- Thank you for your response, and putting up with a newbie at programming, but I am not allowed to use counter (for a class), so is there another way?

Comment: @SamuelM. - gnibbler's response should work for you. Use the `sorted` function. His answer is just a snippet though, you need to change your code to use it.

Comment: @BrendanLong- So get rid of the print x, occ[x] and add the programming in or do something more then that???

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use Counter, I'd do something like this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

with open(name, 'r') as f:
    raw_text = f.read().lower()

letterCounts = [raw_text.count(letter) for letter in ascii_lowercase]

frequencies = reversed(sorted(zip(ascii_lowercase, letterCounts), lambda x: x[1]))

for i in frequencies:
    print "%s: %d" % i
```

Comment: This will work, but if the input file were very large, this would be quite slow.  It will read the entire file into memory, then make another copy of the entire file, the copy being lower case.  Then it will make 26 separate passes over the entire file, counting letter occurrences.  I like the use of `ascii_lowercase`; that's a good one to remember!

Comment: Yes this is O(N^2) i think. Also i just found out about `ascii_lowercase` too... i will use that inseat of `string.lowercase[:26]`

Comment: In fairness, this is pretty much what the question shows, just cleaned up and improved!

Comment: Yeah i was gonna say you should copy/paste your comment to the OP so he can see it too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward Python version using `defaultdict()`.  Since you said this is for a class, this isn't quite the final solution you requested.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

d = defaultdict(int)

name = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

with open(name, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for ch in line:
            if ch.isalpha():
                d[ch] += 1

lst = d.items()

# sort twice: once for alphabetical order, then for frequency (descending).
# Because the Python sort is "stable", we will end up with descending
# frequency, but alphabetical order for any frequency values that are equal.
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

for key, value in lst:
    print value, key,
```

When you do a for loop on an open file, like `for line in f` here, Python will grab one line at a time from the input file.  Then we loop one character at a time on the input line.  Then we check to see if it's a letter, and if so, we increment the frequency count for the letter.

There is a bug in this code.  You want it to count the frequency of all letters as if they were all lower case, but this code will keep one count for upper case and another count for lower case.  I'm sure you can figure out how to modify this so that the counts will be for only lower-case.

Once we are done counting, we use the `.items()` method function to get a list of `(key, value)` tuples.  For example: `('h', 3)` is a tuple with the dictionary key character `h` and its value, the count 3.

Now we want to sort.  I'm showing you a nifty trick that Python can do: since the sort is a "stable" sort, if we do multiple sorts, Python won't disturb the results of earlier sorts unless it must.  What this means is that if we first sort by alphabetical order, and *then* by frequency count, then for all cases where the frequency count is equal we will get alphabetical order within that frequency.  So, since `a`, `b`, and `c` are all the same frequency (they each appear once) you would expect part of the output to be: `1 a 1 b 1 c`

Now, I'm being a bit tricky but this is good to learn.  The sort function can take an argument called `key` which controls the sort.  `key` should be a function that returns a value to be used for sorting. Since we have a list of tuples, we want a key function that can get part of the tuple and return it.  We could write two functions:

```
def get_key(kv_tuple):
    return kv_tuple[0]
def get_value(kv_tuple):
    return kv_tuple[1]
```

But Python has a function, `operator.itemgetter()`, which we can use.  It will make a key function for us that will get part of the tuple for us, if we just tell it which position in the tuple we want to get.

Since we want the frequency to be sorted by largest value first, we also set `reverse=True` in the arguments to the `.sort()` method.

Finally we loop over the list of key, value tuples and print.

There is another problem in this code.  Your example output shows that you want every letter to be in the list, with a count of 0 if the letter was not in the input.  This only counts things that were there.

So, I suggest you re-write this code.  Instead of using a `defaultdict`, try using an ordinary `dict`, but have a loop that sets each of the letters `a` to `z` into the `dict` with a count of 0.

I also suggest that after you have your ordinary `dict` that includes the letters you want to count, you change the code that decides whether to count or not.  Currently it uses the `.isalpha()` method function to decide whether to count a character; instead you could check to see if the character is `in` the dictionary.  Then, you could use this code to count punctuation or numbers or any sort of character.

Answer (score 0):

I think a much easier approach would be to use the native count function:

This code simply print the count for each letter. You will need to put this in a collection and sort it for you to get the most frequent letters first.

```
text = 'Your original text.'
alpha = list ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
for letter in alpha:
    print letter + ': ' + str(text.count(letter))
```