# Count frequency of letters in a text file

Tags: python, text

In python, how can I iterate through a text file and count the number of occurrences of each letter? I realise I could just use a 'for x in file' statement to go through it and then set up 26 or so if elif statements, but surely there is a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+count

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5148987/866571) is similar question asked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Letter frequency in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148903/letter-frequency-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
with open(file) as f:
    c = Counter()
    for line in f:
        c += Counter(line)
```

If the file is not so large, you can read all of it into memory as a string and convert it into a `Counter` object in one line of code:

```
c = Counter(f.read())
```

Example:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c += Counter('aaabbbcccddd eee fff ggg')
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, ' ': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 3, 'd': 3, 'g': 3, 'f': 3})
>>> c += Counter('aaabbbccc')
Counter({'a': 6, 'c': 6, 'b': 6, ' ': 3, 'e': 3, 'd': 3, 'g': 3, 'f': 3})
```

or use the [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method of strings:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase     # ascii_lowercase =='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
with open(file) as f:
    text = f.read().strip()
    dic = {}
    for x in ascii_lowercase:
        dic[x] = text.count(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary - basically `letters[char]++`

Answer (score 1):

This way creates a dictionary histogram for each **character**, which could be used to create a bar chart or similar. If you want to limit it to letters or some subset, you'll need to add an extra conditional, or filter `freqs` at the end.

```
freqs = {}
with open('your_filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            if char in freqs:
                freqs[char] += 1
            else:
                freqs[char] = 1

print(freqs)
```

You can also write the same logic using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
freqs = {}
with open('your_filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            freqs.setdefault(char, 0)
            freqs[char] += 1
```

Or using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

freqs = defaultdict(int)
with open('your_filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            freqs[char] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter is a good way to do this, but Counter is only available in 3.1 and up, plus 2.7.

If you're on 3.0 or 2.[56], you probably should use collections.defaultdict(int) instead.

Answer (score 0):

basically, without imports:
is_letter is a function to decide if something is a letter,
so that you can count other things than the usual english letters

```
def add_or_init(dictionary, c):
        if(c in dictionary):
                dictionary[c]+=1
        else:
                dictionary[c]=1
def count_one_letter(dictionary, c, is_letter):
        if is_letter(c):
                add_or_init(dictionary, c)
def count_letters(dictionary, string, is_letter):
        for c in string:
                count_one_letter(dictionary, c, is_letter)
        return dictionary

#count all characters
count_letters(dict(),'aaabbbcccddd eee fff ggg',lambda x: True)
# => {'a': 3, ' ': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 3, 'd': 3, 'g': 3, 'f': 3}
```