# Python: try except KeyError vs if has_key()

Tags: python, performance

In the following code, what's more efficient / more 'Pythonic'? using a try-catch clause or a if-else clause?

```
fname = 'AdobeARM.log'

letters = {}

with open(fname,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            try:
                letters[c] += 1
            except KeyError:
                letters[c] = 1

print letters
```

VS.

```
fname = 'AdobeARM.log'

letters = {}

with open(fname,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            if letters.has_key(c):
                letters[c] += 1
            else:
                letters[c] = 1

print letters
```

I tend to go with the try catch option, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: IMO, second way is more self-explaining. And try-catch must have an overhead.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342207/count-frequency-of-letters-in-a-text-file.

Comment: Noone mentions membeship testing via "in".  "if c in letters:" reads much more cleanly to me IMHO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on your python version, you might want to use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here, as it's the most appropriate.

Now, regarding which alternative is the most pythonic, it depends on the people you're going to ask. On the one hand, [exception-based flow control is sometimes frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4513009/873145), as exceptions are supposed to be raised in exceptional situations, and not to be used as conditionals.

On the other hand, however, there are [situations in which you would rather use try / except](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604717/873145) because conditionals would not be practical.

Finally, from a performance standpoint, it depends on whether you expect your key to be there most of the time (An `if` statement is a bit slower, but an exception is a lot slower *when* it's raised), and if performance is a concern, you should measure your performance with both implementations before deciding.

---

All in all, I think that a general rule of thumb would be to use conditionals by default, but use exceptions if they are more practical / make more sense / give you speedups that you really need.

Answer (score 23):

Use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> `get(key[, default])`
>
> Return the value for key if `key` is in the dictionary, else `default`. If
>   `default` is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never
>   raises a `KeyError`.

In other words `d.get('x', c)` is equivalent to `d['x'] if 'x' in d else c`.

**Example:**

```
In [24]: d = {'a':1, 'b':2}

In [27]: d['d'] = d.get('d', 0) + 1  # 0 is the default value

In [28]: d
Out[28]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}

In [29]: d['d'] = d.get('d', 0) + 1

In [30]: d
Out[30]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 2}
```

Comment: @zenpoy is trying to count letters in a text, and your answer is not doing any calculation!

Comment: I'm not trying to get the value...

Comment: letters[c] = letters.get(c,1)

Comment: @piokuc so `letters[c] = letters.get(c,0) + 1` would be better

Comment: yep, sorry, just wanted to say tbat the Ashwin's answer was not too bad

Comment: @zenpoy poor internet connection didn't allowed me to complete the answer, now done.

Comment: Anyone has any idea whether `get` is implemented with `try-catch` or with `if-else` and why?

Comment: @zenpoy from `help(dict.get)` --> get(...)
 `D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d`.  `d` defaults to `None`. simple ternary operator.

Answer (score 10):

More pythonic is to use a dedicated tool for the job:

```
from collections import Counter

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    letters = Counter(f.read())
```

Also do note that `has_key` is deprecated in favor of `in`.

Answer (score 1):

see if you can use this trick to handle exception pythonically.

```
adict = {}
default = None
val = adict.get('dogname', default)
# val will be None rather than raise an exception.
```

Reference: https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError

Comment: This is Aशwini चhaudhary's answer...